# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loading')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, foreach, react-redux

Gracias por la ayuda el bicho sigue

Gracias. Necesito ayuda para resolver el siguiente error Se hace desde acciones la conexión con el back y se trae por reducer al componente pero tenemos un error al cargar ese componente userlist.
La ruta probada desde postman devuelve los usuarios pero no hemos podido mostrarlos en pantalla

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact'

import MetaData from '../layout/MetaData'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getUsers } from '../../actions/userActions'
import {Link } from "react-router-dom"


//import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'




export const UserList = () => {
    
    const { loading, usuarios} = useSelector(state=> state.users)
    //const alert= useAlert();
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        // if (error){
        //     return alert.error(error)
        // }

        dispatch(getUsers());
    }, [dispatch])


    const setUsers = () => { //funcion para mostrar los usuarios 
        const data = { //data es un objeto
            columns: [ //se reemplaza luego por la data de la base de datos
                {
                    label: 'Name',
                    field: 'name',
                    sort: 'asc'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Email',
                    field: 'email',
                    sort: 'asc'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Password',
                    field: 'passwprd',
                    sort: 'asc'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Avatar',
                    field: 'avatar',
                    sort: 'asc'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Role',
                    field: 'role',
                    sort: 'asc'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Acciones',
                    field: 'actions',
                },
            ],
            rows: [] //tantas filas como productos haya en la base de datos
        }
        usuarios.forEach(user => {
            data.rows.push({ //se reemplaza luego por la data de la base de datos
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password,
                avatar: user.avatar.url,
                role: user.role,
                actions: <Fragment>
                    <Link to={`/usuario/${user._id}`} className="btn btn-primary py-1 px-2">
                        <i className="fa fa-eye"></i>
                        </Link><Link to="/" className="btn btn-warning py-1 px-2" >
                        <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </Link>

                    <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger py-1 px-2">
                        <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </Link> 
                </Fragment>
            })
        })
        return data;
    }

    
        

  return (
    <Fragment>
            <MetaData title={'All Users'} />
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-2">
                    <Sidebar /> {/* sidebar requerido*/}
                </div>

                <div className="col-12 col-md-10">
                    <Fragment>
                        <h1 className="my-5">Usuarios Registrados</h1>

                        {loading ? <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i> :(
                            <MDBDataTable //tabla de mdbreact para mostrar los productos
                                data={setUsers()} //le paso la data que cree con la funcion 
                                setProducts
                                className="px-3"
                                bordered //borde de la tabla
                                striped //filas alternadas
                                hover   //efecto hover en las filas de la tabla 
                            />
                        )}

                    </Fragment>
                </div>
            </div>

        </Fragment>
  )
}

export default UserList
```

Gracias por la ayuda el bicho sigue

Gracias. Necesito ayuda para resolver el siguiente error Se hace desde acciones la conexión con el back y se trae por reducer al componente pero tenemos un error al cargar ese componente userlist

Comment: Por qué harías la llamada desde actions? y porque loading estaría en la store?
La llamada deberías hacerla dentro del useEffect y si hay respuesta ahí harías el dispatch para guardar en la store, una vez que cambie el estado se re-renderizaría el componente donde harías el map o lo que necesites..
En cuanto a loading, generalmente es un estado local, que inicia en true y se pasa a false cuando se termina de obtener la información o de guardarla donde se desea.
Por último en el error cuando dice reading('loading') suele indicar la línea donde se genera el problema y el archivo, sería útil..

Comment: Por otro lado poner el dispatch en el array de dependencias del useEffect tendría mucho sentido, ya que este no va a cambiar. Y si bien esto podría mostrar un warning por la dependencia, lo ideal sería quizás solo poner //eslint-disable-next-line en la línea anterior a la que tiene el array de dependencias. 
Poner en el array de dependencias cualquier cosa que te indiquen los warnings podrían hacerte entrar en un loop infinito si lo que se pone es algo que se está cambiando dentro del mismo useEffect.

Comment: Gracias Luis, nos dio una guía para solucionar. Ahora tenemos otro error

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Comment: Parece que no existe usuarios, entonces explota el forEach.. podrías hacer un condicional rendering ejemplo, usuarios && usuarios.forEach....